# SQL cuts polish diacritics

Tags: sql, diacritics

I'm using Microsoft SQL Server Express Edition 9.00.5000.00 and after inserting varchar(max) gęś it convert this text to ges, how to unset this option to have gęś in my database?

Comment: Use `NVARCHAR` as the datatype for the column, and when inserting from T-SQL, always use the `N'....'` notation for string literals!

Comment: And how to sen that in LINQ to SQL?

Comment: Can't say anything without seeing **actual code** to see if you're missing something ....